# statsmodel logit results very different from R and Stata

Tags: logistic-regression, statsmodels

I am fitting a logistic regression using SAT scores to predict a binary outcome - the bivariate correlation is 0.17. Stata and R (aod package) both give a logit coefficient of 0.004, but statsmodel (python) gives -0.0013 (I have tried both MLE and IRLS). There is no missing data, and the number of observations is exactly the same across all three platforms – it is the same .csv file being used in each case.

R:

```
Call:
glm(formula = df$outcome ~ df$sat, family = "binomial", data = df)

Deviance Residuals: 
    Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
-0.7527  -0.5911  -0.4778  -0.3406   3.0509  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept) -7.758e+00  6.274e-02  -123.7   <2e-16 ***
df$sat       4.151e-03  4.351e-05    95.4   <2e-16 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for binomial family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 257024  on 334357  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 245878  on 334356  degrees of freedom
AIC: 245882

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 5
```

Stata:

```
. logit outcome sat

Iteration 0:   log likelihood = -128512.03  
Iteration 1:   log likelihood = -123233.13  
Iteration 2:   log likelihood = -122939.88  
Iteration 3:   log likelihood =  -122939.1  
Iteration 4:   log likelihood =  -122939.1  

Logistic regression                             Number of obs     =    334,358
                                                LR chi2(1)        =   11145.86
                                                Prob > chi2       =     0.0000
Log likelihood =  -122939.1                     Pseudo R2         =     0.0434

------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     outcome |      Coef.   Std. Err.      z    P>|z|     [95% Conf. Interval]
-------------+----------------------------------------------------------------
         sat |   .0041509   .0000435    95.40   0.000     .0040656    .0042362
       _cons |   -7.75775   .0627402  -123.65   0.000    -7.880719   -7.634782
```

Statsmodel:

```
Optimization terminated successfully.
         Current function value: 0.399258
         Iterations 5
                           Logit Regression Results                           
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                outcome   No. Observations:               334358
Model:                          Logit   Df Residuals:                   334357
Method:                           MLE   Df Model:                            0
Date:                Wed, 15 Jul 2015   Pseudo R-squ.:                -0.03878
Time:                        13:09:47   Log-Likelihood:            -1.3350e+05
converged:                       True   LL-Null:                   -1.2851e+05
                                        LLR p-value:                     1.000
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sat           -0.0013   3.69e-06   -363.460      0.000        -0.001    -0.001


==============================================================================
                 Generalized Linear Model Regression Results                  
==============================================================================
Dep. Variable:                outcome   No. Observations:               334358
Model:                            GLM   Df Residuals:                   334357
Model Family:                Binomial   Df Model:                            0
Link Function:                  logit   Scale:                             1.0
Method:                          IRLS   Log-Likelihood:            -1.3350e+05
Date:                Wed, 15 Jul 2015   Deviance:                   2.6699e+05
Time:                        13:09:48   Pearson chi2:                 3.50e+05
No. Iterations:                     7                                         
==============================================================================
                 coef    std err          z      P>|z|      [95.0% Conf. Int.]
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
sat           -0.0013   3.69e-06   -363.460      0.000        -0.001    -0.001
==============================================================================
```

Comment: You are missing the constant in the statsmodels version. You only have the slope coefficient in the summary. If you use the formula interface, then the constant is automatically included as in Stata and R. In the array interface the design matrix is used as it is given and you have to add the constant yourself. See several related stackoverflow questions.

Comment: Thank you, user 333700. The other questions I noticed about this issue looked like they had to do with how Python handled missing values. Cheers.

Comment: Missing value handling is similar to adding a constant, in that it defaults to `drop`ping observations in the formulas, largely because of patsy, but defaults to ignoring and not even checking in the array interface. See `missing` option in the models.